# Como posso mostrar valor do banco de dados em tempo real?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Sou iniciante em php, Muito menos em js. eu gostaria de pegar a contagem de quantos usuarios estão cadastrados no meu banco de dados, porém em tempo real utilizando ajax. 
Já tentei de muitas formas, porém sem sucesso. por enquanto tenho somente em código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$conta = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

o resultado que vem de $conta é oque quero colocar num `<span id="users"</span>`
só que se eu simplismente colocar um `echo $conta` dentro do span, não será em tempo real o valor que irá sair... a "logica' seria, em um arquivo ter a query com a contagem de linhas da tabela usuarios, e em outra página que tiver o span ficar requisitando o valor que vem da variavel $conta.

**Oque preciso:**

*Mostrar em tempo real usando ajax o valor de uma string que conta quantas linhas tem na tabela "usuarios" em um `<span id="users"></span>`*

Comment: Vc vai precisar de um banco de dados em tempo real, que não é o caso do MySql, procure por Firebase, deve suprir suas necessidades

Comment: Poderia usar Ajax requisitando de segundos em segundos.

Comment: Bom, eu quiz dizer utilizando ajax... porém não sei como posso fazer isto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar Ajax, mas não é bem em *tempo real*. No exemplo abaixo, as requisições são chamadas de 2 em 2 segundos (você pode alterar o tempo para mais ou menos, porém, quanto menor o tempo, poderá sobrecarregar o servidor com requisições seguidas em curto espaço de tempo. Avalie isso).

```
function ajx(){
   var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); // cria o objeto XHR
   ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      // verifica quando o Ajax for completado
      if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
         document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = ajax.responseText; // atualiza o span
         setTimeout(ajx, 2000); // chama a função novamente após 2 segundos
      }
   }
   ajax.open("GET", "pagina.php"); // página a ser requisitada
   ajax.send(); // envia a requisição
}
ajx(); // chama a função
```

> Substitua `pagina.php` pela página onde você está fazendo o `echo`.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.

Comment: O AP vai ficar em uma pagina e olhando se há novos registros de 2 em 2 segundos? Desperdício de recursos. Um iframezinho com link atualizar

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Pois eh... como faria isso sem fazer requisições de quando em quando?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo legal, mas e se o cara não quer ficar clicando pra atualizar?

Comment: Ai faz o que você mandou, rs

Answer (score 0):

Vou começar colocando o dedo no que eu penso que é erro.
Que razao alguem teria para Mostrar apenas a quantidade de cadastrados?

Acho que assim esteja errada.Penso que queira Contar os usuarios com determinado nome se for : **"é ERRADO"**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$conta = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Se eu estiver certo você vai ter um criterio para contar...é **"CORRETO"**
Coloque uma no seu html 
 `<div id="user"></div>` 
e um campo responsavel por resceber o seu criterio

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="Digite o nome da cidade"name="Campo" id="Campo" onchange="PgReal(this.value);/>
```

A função é executanda **`OnChange`** Quando mudar o valor do campo E vai retornar os valores :
Preste atençao nesse = **Arquivo.php?CampoNome**

```
$variavelCampoNome=$_GET['CampoNome'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE `Coluna` LIKE '%$variavelCampoNome%'";
if ($Resultado = mysql_query($sql)){ // Se ele conseguir executar
$conta = mysql_num_rows($Resultado);//faz a contagem
if ($conta==0){ //se FOR IGUAL A ZERO
echo 'Nenhuma Informação encontrada com esse criterio';
}else{ //Mostra a quantidade SE FOR DIFERENTE DE ZERO
echo '<span id="users">.$conta</span>';
while($Linha = mysql_fetch_array($Resultado)) {

//Criterios para exibir 
$VariavelColuna=$Linha[ColunaExibir];
echo $VariavelColuna;

}

}
```

Agora a função .

```
function PgReal(str) {

    if (str == "") {
return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = this.responseText; //Copia a resposta Para o div id=user
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","Arquivo.php?CampoNome="+str,true);//Exececuta o chamado usando o valor do campo que você colocou o botao ONCHANGE
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
```

ACHO QUE ERA ISSO QUE VOCÊ REALMENTE QUERIA. Mais aja internet pra isso.
EDITE COMO E ONDE ACHAR MELHOR!Boa sorte